# Jumbotron is not showing in bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am currently new to using bootstrap and have come across a problem regarding the jumbotron. When I apply it, it does not show but everything inside does. This is the code:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Boostrap Testing</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bs/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="bs/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bs/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    
    <div class="container">
      <div class="jumbotron">
          <h1>Home page is coming soon!</h1>
          <p>This website!<p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Test this button!</a>

      </div>
    </div>



  </body>
</html>
```

I have a folder that I installed that contains all of the `.min` files. I have checked and they all don't seem to have any problems. Does anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: What version of Bootstrap?

Comment: The version is 5.1.3

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/migration/#jumbotron and https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/examples/jumbotron/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Bootstrap 5 migration document](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/migration/#jumbotron), Jumbotron was "Dropped".

> The jumbotron component as it can be replicated with utilities. [See
> our new Jumbotron example for a demo](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/examples/jumbotron/).

A BS5 example they provide is:

```
<div class="p-5 mb-4 bg-light rounded-3">
  <div class="container-fluid py-5">
    <h1 class="display-5 fw-bold">Custom jumbotron</h1>
    <p class="col-md-8 fs-4">Using a series of utilities, you can create this jumbotron, just like the one in previous versions of Bootstrap. Check out the examples below for how you can remix and restyle it to your liking.</p>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="button">Example button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```